# Escaped newlines make the code work wrong. Why?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

From a Markdown style guide by Google:

> Because most commandline snippets are intended to be copied and pasted directly into a terminal, it's best practice to escape any newlines. Use a single backslash at the end of the line:
>
> ```bash
> bazel run :target -- --flag --foo=longlonglonglonglongvalue \
> --bar=anotherlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongvalue
> ```

Could someone explain why escaping newlines in the following snippet makes it work wrong if I copy-and-paste it into a terminal (I use zsh on a Mac, not sure the same issue happens in pure Bash and/or in other terminals. Does it?):

If you copy-and-paste this snippet into a terminal, it works fine:

```bash
for (( counter=10; counter>0; counter-- ))
do
echo -n "$counter "
done
printf "\n"
```

But if you copy-and-paste this one, there will be an error:

```bash
for (( counter=10; counter>0; counter-- )) \
do \
echo -n "$counter " \
done \
printf "\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shell syntax, there is a semicolon (`;`) token which separates commands.

As an alternative a newline can be used. In other words, you can do this:

```
command ; command
```

or this:

```
command
command
```

Certain syntactic constructs in the shell consist of multiple commands, like looping:

```
while test-command1; test-comand2 ; do command1; command2; command3; done
```

Syntactically, this is six commands: a `while` command which marks the start of a sequence of test commands which control the loop. Then a `do` command which marks the start of the loop body. Finally a `done` command that marks the end.

When this is written on multiple lines, the semicolons become optional:

```
while test-command-1
      test-command-2
do    command1
      command2
      command3
done
```

Now the backslash-newline sequence, often called a line continuation, turns multiple physical lines into a single logical line.  A similar line-continuation feature is found in the Awk language, in the Make language and in the preprocessing feature of the C language.

When we break a shell script into multiple physical lines with line continuations, the interpreter sees only a single line.  Therefore, the semicolons are required.

Wrong:

```
while test-command-1 \
      test-command-2 \
do    command1 \
      command2 \
      command3 \
done
```

Right:

```
while test-command-1 ; \
      test-command-2 ; \
do    command1 ; \
      command2 ; \
      command3 ; \
done
```

It's very common to see this in in a `Makefile`. In Make, every line of a build recipe is a separate shell script run in a separate shell instance. Thus every script must fit into a single logical line of the make syntax. Line continuations are used to break complex shell scripts into multiple physical lines, and so the semicolons are required.

Answer (score 2):

`\` followed by a newline is a *line-continuation*, it's used to break very long lines into more than one generally for legibility.

The shell upon reading them, just removes them:

```
ec\
ho t\
est
```

Is just another way to write:

```
echo test
```

And:

```
for (( counter=10; counter>0; counter-- )) \
do \
echo -n "$counter " \
done \
printf "\n"
```

Is another way to write:

```
for (( counter=10; counter>0; counter-- )) do echo -n "$counter " done printf "\n"
```

Which would run `echo -n "$counter " done printf "\n"` in a loop, except it's missing the `done` to close the  loop (the other `done` is just an argument to `echo`).

So you may want to insert some `\<newline>` to break very long lines, but you *don't* want to replace `<newline>`s (which are used to delimit commands among other things) with `\<newline>` which is the same as *nothing*¹.

---

<sup>¹ except inside single quotes (or `$'...'` for those shells that support that) or here-documents with quoted delimiters (as in `<< "EOF"...EOF`)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Newline (`NL`, `^J`) marks End-Of Line, and usually ends a command.

Escaped NL characters are treated as a blank, and don't end commands, or lines.

```
foo
bar
```

are two commands.

```
foo \
bar
```

is one command,

```
foo bar
```

Comment: no, escaped newlines disappear completely, they're not replaced by a blank. `foo \<nl>bar` is the same as `foo bar` because you had a space there just before the backslash